# Ошибка в html коде

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
    <head><script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript" charset="windows-1251"></script>
        <center>
            <title>{PAGE_TITLE}</title>
            <meta name="keywords" content="{PAGE_META_KEYWORDS}" />
            <meta name="description" content="{PAGE_META_DESCRIPTION}" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru" />
            <link rel="icon" href="{ASSETS_IMAGES_PATH}favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{ASSETS_IMAGES_PATH}favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?48"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                VK.init({apiId: API_ID, onlyWidgets: true});
            </script>
            <!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Like block will be -->
            <div id="vk_like"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "button", height: 18});
            </script>
            <!-- SEO параметр определяющий главную страницу для фильтрации её дублей -->
            {% IF PAGE_CANONICAL %}
            <link rel="canonical" href="{PAGE_CANONICAL}" />
            {% ENDIF %}

            <!-- Стили которые не нужно менять, грузятся из папки общих файлов -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{FORALL_STYLES_PATH}reset_03.css" type="text/css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{FORALL_STYLES_PATH}nyroModal/nyroModal.full.css" type="text/css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{FORALL_STYLES_PATH}jquery-ui/jquery.ui.all.min.css" type="text/css" />

            <!-- Если в тарифном плане подключен модуль отзывов о товаре -->
            {% IF TARIFF_FEATURE_GOODS_OPINION %}
            <!-- Если не выключен модуль отзывов о товаре, то загружаем css для рейтинга -->
            {% IFNOT SETTINGS_OPINION_DISABLE %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{FORALL_STYLES_PATH}jquery-ui-stars/jquery.ui.stars.min.css" type="text/css" />
            {% ENDIF %}
            {% ENDIF %}

            <!-- Стили магазина -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{ASSETS_STYLES_PATH}main.css" type="text/css" />

            <!-- Скрипты которые не нужно менять, грузятся из папки общих файлов -->
            <!-- Это собранные в один файл скрипты из файлов:
                {FORALL_JS_PATH}jquery-1.4.2.min.js
                {FORALL_JS_PATH}jquery.nyroModal-1.6.2.min.js
                {FORALL_JS_PATH}jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js
                {FORALL_JS_PATH}jquery.validate.min.js
                {FORALL_JS_PATH}jquery.capslock.min.js
            -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{FORALL_JS_PATH}jquery-1.4.2_nyroModal-1.6.2_validate_capslock_jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Если в тарифном плане подключен модуль отзывов о товаре -->
            {% IF TARIFF_FEATURE_GOODS_OPINION %}
            <!-- Если не выключен модуль отзывов о товаре, то загружаем css для рейтинга -->
            {% IFNOT SETTINGS_OPINION_DISABLE %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{FORALL_JS_PATH}jquery.ui.stars.min.js"></script>
            {% ENDIF %}
            {% ENDIF %}

            <!-- Скрипты магазина -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{ASSETS_JS_PATH}main.js"></script>
            <!-- Загрузка Jquery галереии Nyvo Slider -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{ASSETS_STYLES_PATH}nyvo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script src="{ASSETS_JS_PATH}jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-32803384-1']);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();

            </script>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="b_page" id="wrapper">
                <div class="container" id="header">

                    <div class="pad-box cont620" id="logo"><h1><a href="http://{NET_DOMAIN}/"><span>На главную</span></a></h1></div>

                    <!-- Контакты -->
                    <div id="contactInfo">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="contactInfoContent">
                                    <table>
                                        <!-- Первый контактный телефон -->
                                        {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_NUMBER1 %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="contentTableHeadMainPhone">
                                                {SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE1} {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_CITY_CODE1 %}({SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_CITY_CODE1}){% ENDIF %} {SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_NUMBER1}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% ENDIF %}

                                        <!-- Второй контактный телефон -->
                                        {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_NUMBER2 %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="contentTableHeadMainPhone"><a style="font-size:11pt;"</a>
                                                {SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE2} {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_CITY_CODE2 %}({SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_CITY_CODE2}){% ENDIF %} {SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_NUMBER2}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% ENDIF %}

                                        <!-- Третий контактный телефон -->
                                        {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_NUMBER3 %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="contentTableHeadMainPhone"><a style="font size:11pt;"</a>
                                                {SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE3} {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_CITY_CODE3 %}({SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_CITY_CODE3}){% ENDIF %} {SETTINGS_STORE_PHONE_NUMBER3}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% ENDIF %}

                                        <!-- Время работы магазина -->
                                        {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_WORK_TIME %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="contentTableHeadMainWorkTime">
                                                {SETTINGS_STORE_WORK_TIME}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% ENDIF %}

                                        <!-- Вывод e-mail -->
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a style="font-size:11pt;" href="mailto:rastuigraya@mail.ru">rastuigraya@mail.ru</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <!-- ICQ номер -->
                                        {% IF SETTINGS_STORE_ICQ %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="contentTableHeadMainIcq">
                                                <img class="valignMiddle" src="http://wwp.icq.com/scripts/online.dll?icq={SETTINGS_STORE_ICQ_ONLY_DIGITS}&img=27" alt="Статус" width="16" height="16" />
                                                <span class="valignMiddle">{SETTINGS_STORE_ICQ}</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% ENDIF %}
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end Контакты -->

                    <!-- Корзина -->
                    <div id="cartInfo">
                        <a href="{CART_URL}">в корзине товаров на</a>:
                        <span id="cartSum">
                            {% IF cart_count_empty %}
                            <span>0</span> {CURRENCY_NAME}
                            {% ELSE %}
                            {% FOR cart_sum %}
                            <span class="num">{cart_sum.NOW | money_format}</span><br />
                            {% ENDFOR %}
                            {% ENDIF %}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end Корзина -->

                    <!-- Поиск -->
                    <div id="search">
                        <form action="http://{NET_DOMAIN}/search" id="searchform" method="get">
                            <div>
                                <input type="text"  value="{% IF SEARCH_QUERY %}{SEARCH_QUERY}{%ELSE%}Поиск{%ENDIF%}" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='') ? 'Поиск' : this.value;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Поиск') ? '' : this.value;" id="s" class="search_box alignleft" name="q" />
                                <input type="image" class="submit alignright" src="{ASSETS_IMAGES_PATH}search_but.gif" />
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <!-- end Поиск -->

                    <!-- Верхний блок навигации -->
                    <div class="containerin" id="top-menu">
                        <ul class="pad-box cont620" id="mainmenu">
                            {% FOR menu %}
                            {% FOR header %}
                            {% FOR links %}
                            <li><a href="{menu.header.links.URL}" {% IF menu.header.links.SELECTED %}class="selected"{%ENDIF%} {% IF menu.header.links.TITLE %}title="{menu.header.links.TITLE}"{% ENDIF %}>{menu.header.links.NAME}</a></li>
                            {% ENDFOR %}
                            {% ENDFOR %}
                            {% ENDFOR %}
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- end Верхний блок навигации -->
                </div>

                <!-- контент -->
                <div class="container" id="cpages">
                    <div class="content_page">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="content_body cont700">

                                    {BODY}
                                    <!-- Nyvo слайдер который отображается на главной -->
                                    {% IF index_page %}
                                    <!-- Обёртка, указывающая стиль темы -->
                                    <div class="theme-default" style="padding:1em;display:none;">
                                        <!-- Непосредственный код слайдера -->
                                        <div id="slider">
                                            <img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444792/Logika.png" alt="" title="" />
                                            <img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444785/Bez_imeni2.png" alt="" title="Доставка по всей России" />
                                            <img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444754/Bez_imeni.png" alt="" title="Для детских и дошкольных учреждений скидка -10%" />
                                            <img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444729/vkladyshi.png" alt="" title="Именинникам месяца - скидка 5%" />
                                            <img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444770/Muzykal_nye_igrushki.png" alt="" title="При заказе от 5000 руб.- доставка бесплатно!" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Запуск слайдера -->
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(window).load(function() {
                                            $('#slider').nivoSlider().parent().show();
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    {% ENDIF %}

                                    <!-- Всевозможные списки товаров -->
                                    {% IF index_page %}
                                    <!-- Список новинок на главной -->
                                    {% IFNOT index_page_new_goods_empty %}
                                    <div class="pad-box">
                                        <h3><a href="{CATALOG_NEW_URL}" class="indexPage">Новинки</a></h3>
                                        {% FOR index_page_new_goods %}
                                        <div class="listing">
                                            <div class="imagem"><a href="{index_page_new_goods.URL}"><img {% IF index_page_new_goods.IMAGE_EMPTY %}src="{ASSETS_IMAGES_PATH}no-photo-medium.png" width="220"{% ELSE %}src="{index_page_new_goods.IMAGE_SMALL}"{% ENDIF %} alt="{index_page_new_goods.NAME}" /></a></div>

                                            <div class="contm">
                                                <h3><a href="{index_page_new_goods.URL}">{index_page_new_goods.NAME}</a></h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    {index_page_new_goods.DESCRIPTION_SHORT}
                                                </p>
                                                <p>
                                                    Цена: <a href="{index_page_new_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_NOW}">{index_page_new_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW | money_format}</a><br />
                                                    {% IF index_page_new_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT>index_page_new_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW %}
                                                    Цена без учёта скидки: <a href="{index_page_new_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT}" class="lineThrough">{index_page_new_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT | money_format}</a>
                                                    {% ELSEIF index_page_new_goods.MIN_PRICE_OLD>index_page_new_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW %}
                                                    Старая цена: <a href="{index_page_new_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_OLD}" class="lineThrough">{index_page_new_goods.MIN_PRICE_OLD | money_format}</a>
                                                    {% ENDIF %}
                                                </p>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a class="readmore" title="{index_page_new_goods.NAME}" href="{index_page_new_goods.URL}">Подробнее</a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clr"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% ENDFOR index_page_new_goods %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% ENDIF %}       
                                    <!-- end Список новинок на главной -->

                                    <!-- Список хитов продаж на главной -->
                                    {% IFNOT index_page_favorites_goods_empty %}
                                    <div class="pad-box">
                                        <h3><a href="{CATALOG_TOP_SALES_URL}" class="indexPage">Хиты продаж</a></h3>
                                        {% FOR index_page_favorites_goods %}
                                        <div class="listing">
                                            <div class="imagem"><a href="{index_page_favorites_goods.URL}"><img {% IF index_page_favorites_goods.IMAGE_EMPTY %}src="{ASSETS_IMAGES_PATH}no-photo-medium.png" width="220"{% ELSE %}src="{index_page_favorites_goods.IMAGE_SMALL}"{% ENDIF %} alt="{index_page_favorites_goods.NAME}" /></a></div>

                                            <div class="contm">
                                                <h3><a href="{index_page_favorites_goods.URL}">{index_page_favorites_goods.NAME}</a></h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    {index_page_favorites_goods.DESCRIPTION_SHORT}
                                                </p>
                                                <p>
                                                    Цена: <a href="{index_page_favorites_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_NOW}">{index_page_favorites_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW | money_format}</a><br />
                                                    {% IF index_page_favorites_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT>index_page_favorites_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW %}
                                                    Цена без учёта скидки: <a href="{index_page_favorites_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT}" class="lineThrough">{index_page_favorites_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT | money_format}</a>
                                                    {% ELSEIF index_page_favorites_goods.MIN_PRICE_OLD>index_page_favorites_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW %}
                                                    Старая цена: <a href="{index_page_favorites_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_OLD}" class="lineThrough">{index_page_favorites_goods.MIN_PRICE_OLD | money_format}</a>
                                                    {% ENDIF %}
                                                </p>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a class="readmore" title="{index_page_favorites_goods.NAME}" href="{index_page_favorites_goods.URL}">Подробнее</a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clr"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% ENDFOR index_page_favorites_goods %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% ENDIF %}       
                                    <!-- end Список хитов продаж на главной -->

                                    <!-- Список товаров на главной -->
                                    {% IFNOT index_page_goods_empty %}
                                    <div class="pad-box">
                                        <h3>Интересные предложения</h3>
                                        {% FOR index_page_goods %}
                                        <div class="listing">
                                            <div class="imagem"><a href="{index_page_goods.URL}"><img {% IF index_page_goods.IMAGE_EMPTY %}{ASSETS_IMAGES_PATH}src="{ASSETS_IMAGES_PATH}no-photo-medium.png" width="220"{% ELSE %}src="{index_page_goods.IMAGE_SMALL}"{% ENDIF %} alt="{index_page_goods.NAME}" /></a></div>

                                            <div class="contm">
                                                <h3><a href="{index_page_goods.URL}">{index_page_goods.NAME}</a></h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    {index_page_goods.DESCRIPTION_SHORT}
                                                </p>
                                                <p>
                                                    Цена: <a href="{index_page_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_NOW}">{index_page_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW | money_format}</a><br />
                                                    {% IF index_page_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT>index_page_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW %}
                                                    Цена без учёта скидки: <a href="{index_page_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT}" class="lineThrough">{index_page_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT | money_format}</a>
                                                    {% ELSEIF index_page_goods.MIN_PRICE_OLD>index_page_goods.MIN_PRICE_NOW %}
                                                    Старая цена: <a href="{index_page_goods.URL_MIN_PRICE_OLD}" class="lineThrough">{index_page_goods.MIN_PRICE_OLD | money_format}</a>
                                                    {% ENDIF %}
                                                </p>
                                                <p>
                                                    <a class="readmore" title="{index_page_goods.NAME}" href="{index_page_goods.URL}">Подробнее</a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clr"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% ENDFOR index_page_goods %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% ENDIF %}       
                                    <!-- end Список товаров на главной -->
                                    {% ENDIF %}
                                    <!-- END Всевозможные списки товаров -->
                                </td>
                                <td class="content_catalog cont250">
                                    <!-- Каталог -->
                                    <div class="pad-box">
                                        <ul class="leftmenu"> 
                                            <li><h3><a href="{CATALOG_URL}">Каталог товаров</a></h3>
                                                <ul>
                                                    {%IFNOT catalog_empty %}
                                                    {% FOR catalog %}
                                                    {% IFNOT catalog.HIDE %}
                                                    <li class="cat-item">
                                                        <font color="orange">
                                                            <a href="{catalog.URL}" 
                                                            {% IF catalog.LEVEL>0%}style="padding-left:{catalog.LEVEL | multiply("20")}px"{% ENDIF %}
                                                            {% IF catalog.CURRENT %}class="selected"{% ENDIF %}
                                                            >{catalog.NAME}</a>
                                                        </font>
                                                    </li>
                                                    {% ENDIF %}
                                                    {% ENDFOR %}
                                                    {% ENDIF %}
                                                </ul><br />
                                                <div class="banner" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444526/8a7ec770ad1c2b81cc337c0cf2c279b8.png"</a>
                                                    <a href="http://www.servis-okna.ucoz.ru"><img src="http://servis-okna.ucoz.ru/baner4.jpg" align="right" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" height="60">

                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                            <!-- Если в тарифном плане подключен модуль фильтров по товарам -->
                                            {% IF TARIFF_FEATURE_GOODS_FILTERS %}
                                            <!-- Фильтры по товарам. Появляются только на странице категории и поиска по товарам -->
                                            {% IF SHOW_GOODS_FILTERS %}
                                            <li class="goods_filters"><br /><h2>Фильтры</h2>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <!-- Форма поиска отправляет всегда на ту же страницу, на которой находится пользователь -->
                                                    <form action="" method="get">
                                                        <div class="contentTbodySearchFilterBlock cornerAll">

                                                            <!-- Фильтры по характеристикам товаров (Например: Производитель, разрешение экрана, заряд аккомулятора) -->
                                                            {% FOR filter_attr_list %}
                                                            <span class="contentTbodySearchFilterBlockHeader">{filter_attr_list.NAME}</span>
                                                            <div class="contentTbodySearchFilterBlockValues">
                                                                {% FOR values %}
                                                                <input type="checkbox" name="form[filter][attr][{filter_attr_list.ID}][{filter_attr_list.values.ID}]" value="1" id="filterAttrVal{filter_attr_list.values.ID}" {% IF filter_attr_list.values.CHECKED %}checked="checked"{% ENDIF %} /> 
                                                                <label for="filterAttrVal{filter_attr_list.values.ID}">{filter_attr_list.values.VALUE}</label><br />
                                                                {% ENDFOR %}
                                                            </div>
                                                            {% ENDFOR %}

                                                            <!-- Фильтры по свойствам товарных модификаций (Например: Цвет, размер, модификация) -->
                                                            {% FOR filter_prop_list %}
                                                            <span class="contentTbodySearchFilterBlockHeader">{filter_prop_list.NAME}</span>
                                                            <div class="contentTbodySearchFilterBlockValues">
                                                                {% FOR values %}
                                                                <input type="checkbox" name="form[filter][prop][{filter_prop_list.ID}][{filter_prop_list.values.ID}]" value="1" id="filterPropVal{filter_prop_list.values.ID}" {% IF filter_prop_list.values.CHECKED %}checked="checked"{% ENDIF %} > 
                                                                <label for="filterPropVal{filter_prop_list.values.ID}">{filter_prop_list.values.VALUE}</label><br />
                                                                {% ENDFOR %}
                                                            </div>
                                                            {% ENDFOR %}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            {% ENDIF %}
                                            {% ENDIF %}
                                            <!-- END Если в тарифном плане подключен модуль фильтров по товарам -->

                                            <!-- Если в тарифном плане подключен модуль сравнения товаров -->
                                            {% IF TARIFF_FEATURE_GOODS_COMPARE %}
                                            <!-- Если не выключен модуль сравнения товаров, то покажем этот блок -->
                                            {% IFNOT SETTINGS_COMPARE_DISABLE %}
                                            <li class="compare"><br /><h2><a href="{COMPARE_URL}">Сравнить товары</a></h2>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <div class="contentTbodyCompare">
                                                        {%IF COMPARE_GOODS_COUNT=0 %}
                                                        <em class="contentTbodyCompareEmpty">Нет товаров для сравнения</em>
                                                        {% ELSE %}
                                                        <em>Товаров на сравнении: {COMPARE_GOODS_COUNT} шт.</em><br />
                                                        <a class="contentTbodyCompareDetails" href="{COMPARE_URL}">Посмотреть</a>
                                                        {% ENDIF %}
                                                    </div>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            {% ENDIF %}
                                            {% ENDIF %}
                                            <!-- END Если в тарифном плане подключен модуль сравнения товаров -->

                                            <!-- Если в тарифном плане подключен модуль новостей -->
                                            {% IF TARIFF_FEATURE_NEWS %}
                                            <!-- Все новости -->
                                            {%IFNOT news_list_all_empty %}
                                            <li class="news_all"><br /><h2><a href="{NEWS_ALL_URL}">Лента новостей</a></h2>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <div class="contentTbodyNews">

                                                        <!-- Список новостей магазина -->
                                                        <p class="contentTbodyNewsBlock">
                                                            {% FOR news_list_all %}
                                                            <div class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItem"> 
                                                                <a href="{news_list_all.URL}" class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTitle" title="Перейти к странице новости">{news_list_all.TITLE}</a><br />

                                                                <div class="newsListBlockItemPreview">{news_list_all.TEXT_SHORT} </div>
                                                                {% IF news_list_all.SHOW_TIME %}<em class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTime">{news_list_all.TIME | date("d.m.Y")}</em><br />{% ENDIF %}
                                                            </div>
                                                            {% ENDFOR %}
                                                            <a class="contentTbodyNewsArchive" href="{NEWS_ALL_URL}">Архив новостей</a>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            {% ENDIF %}

                                            <!-- Новости магазина -->
                                            {%IFNOT news_list_shop_empty %}
                                            <li class="news_shop"><br /><h2><a href="{NEWS_SHOP_URL}">Новости магазина</a></h2>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <div class="contentTbodyNews">

                                                        <!-- Список новостей магазина -->
                                                        <p class="contentTbodyNewsBlock">
                                                            {% FOR news_list_shop %}
                                                            <div class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItem"> 
                                                                <a href="{news_list_shop.URL}" class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTitle" title="Перейти к странице новости">{news_list_shop.TITLE}</a><br />

                                                                <div class="newsListBlockItemPreview">{news_list_shop.TEXT_SHORT} </div>
                                                                {% IF news_list_shop.SHOW_TIME %}<em class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTime">{news_list_shop.TIME | date("d.m.Y")}</em><br />{% ENDIF %}
                                                            </div>
                                                            {% ENDFOR %}
                                                            <a class="contentTbodyNewsArchive" href="{NEWS_SHOP_URL}">Архив новостей</a>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            {% ENDIF %}

                                            <!-- Статьи -->
                                            {%IFNOT news_list_articles_empty %}
                                            <li class="news_articles"><br /><h2><a href="{NEWS_ARTICLES_URL}">Статьи</a></h2>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <div class="contentTbodyNews">

                                                        <!-- Список статей -->
                                                        <p class="contentTbodyNewsBlock">
                                                            {% FOR news_list_articles %}
                                                            <div class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItem"> 
                                                                <a href="{news_list_articles.URL}" class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTitle" title="Перейти к странице новости">{news_list_articles.TITLE}</a><br />

                                                                <div class="newsListBlockItemPreview">{news_list_articles.TEXT_SHORT} </div>
                                                                {% IF news_list_articles.SHOW_TIME %}<em class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTime">{news_list_articles.TIME | date("d.m.Y")}</em><br />{% ENDIF %}
                                                            </div>
                                                            {% ENDFOR %}
                                                            <a class="contentTbodyNewsArchive" href="{NEWS_ARTICLES_URL}">Архив статей</a>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            {% ENDIF %}

                                            <!-- Материалы СМИ -->
                                            {%IFNOT news_list_mass_media_empty %}
                                            <li class="news_mass_media"><br /><h2><a href="{NEWS_MASS_MEDIA_URL}">Новости СМИ</a></h2>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <div class="contentTbodyNews">

                                                        <!-- Список статей -->
                                                        <p class="contentTbodyNewsBlock">
                                                            {% FOR news_list_mass_media %}
                                                            <div class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItem"> 
                                                                <a href="{news_list_mass_media.URL}" class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTitle" title="Перейти к странице новости">{news_list_mass_media.TITLE}</a><br />

                                                                <div class="newsListBlockItemPreview">{news_list_mass_media.TEXT_SHORT} </div>
                                                                {% IF news_list_mass_media.SHOW_TIME %}<em class="contentTbodyNewsBlockItemTime">{news_list_mass_media.TIME | date("d.m.Y")}</em><br />{% ENDIF %}
                                                            </div>
                                                            {% ENDFOR %}
                                                            <a class="contentTbodyNewsArchive" href="{NEWS_MASS_MEDIA_URL}">Архив новостей</a>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            {% ENDIF %} 
                                            {% ENDIF %}
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <!-- Подвал сайта -->

        <div id="footer">          
            <div class="left">
                <p>{COPYRIGHT_FOR_DESIGN_SHINE} {SETTINGS_STORE_REGION}.© {DATE_YEAR} {SETTINGS_STORE_NAME}. {SETTINGS_STORE_ORG_NAME}. Все права защищены.
                <div></p></div> 
                <ul> 
                    {% FOR menu %}
                    {% FOR footer %}

                    {% FOR links %}<li {% IF menu.footer.links.last %}class="last"{% ENDIF %}><a href="{menu.footer.links.URL}" {% IF menu.footer.links.SELECTED %}class="selected"{%ENDIF%} {% IF menu.footer.links.TITLE %}title="{menu.footer.links.TITLE}"{% ENDIF %}>{menu.footer.links.NAME}</a></li>{% ENDFOR %}          
                    {% ENDFOR %}
                    {% ENDFOR %}

                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <div>{SETTINGS_STORE_HTML_CODE}</div>

                </div>  
                <!-- BEGIN JIVOSITE CODE {literal} -->
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    (function(){ var widget_id = '47346';
                    var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/'+widget_id; var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);})();</script>
                <!-- {/literal} END JIVOSITE CODE -->

            </body>

</html>
```

Comment: отредактировать для читабельности. Что у вас за ошибка?

Comment: О боже, удалить код из вопроса 100%.

@wawtory, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.


Это жесть, теги так круто расположены что валидатору не нравится, мне бы тоже не понравилось

Comment: Похоже менеджер интернет магазина решил выяснить смогут ли они обойтись без программиста.

Comment: нет, просто менеджер магазина, плохо понимает что надо делать)Пытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Валидадор выдал около 40-ка основных ошибок и предупреждений. Самые главные, на которые надо бы обратить внимание - это не закрытые теги. Вот пара кусков кода и таких несколько:

```
<div class="banner" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444526/8a7ec770ad1c2b81cc337c0cf2c279b8.png"</a>
    <!-- (!!!) не закрыт тег <img> -->
    <a href="http://www.servis-okna.ucoz.ru">
    <img src="http://servis-okna.ucoz.ru/baner4.jpg" align="right" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" height="60">
    <!-- (!!!) не закрыт тег <a> -->
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а теперь если не трудно то как закрыть теги,именно на этом куске,дольше поди разберусь

Comment: Вот так:

    <div class="banner" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://files.storeland.ru/web/upload/sitefiles/5/445/444526/8a7ec770ad1c2b81cc337c0cf2c279b8.png"></a>
        <a href="http://www.servis-okna.ucoz.ru">
           <img src="http://servis-okna.ucoz.ru/baner4.jpg" align="right" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" height="60">
        </a>
    </div>

Comment: Ура!!! Спасибо)

Comment: 100 баксов)))

Answer (score -2):

А что собственно `center` делает в `head`? Вроде этого достаточно, чтобы `title` и `meta` отправились в `body`, а там они браузеру не слишком-то и сдались.

Ну и вообще, в валидатор его и разбирайся с ошибками.